# Почему в Alpine Linux невозможно ничего написать в консоли?

Tags: linux, консоль, alpine-linux

При установки и даже после неё невозможно написать даже простую команду, типа `ls`

В чем может быть дело?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю ты пытаешься писать кирилицей, а шрифт её не поддерживает...

Comment: @Fat-Zer то есть в Alpine Linux можно использовать только латиницу? Только английский язык?

Comment: Но команда же звучит 'ls', а не 'ды'. попробуйте узнать, как переключается раскладка клавиатуры в вашей системе и переключить на латиницу. А по поводу отображения букв, то шрифты в консоли надо отдельно настраивать исходя из той кодировки, которую вы установили в системе по умолчанию

Comment: @Ivan, нет конечно;)... просто установи шрифт. обычный выбор — terminus... как именно — смотри доки к дистрибутиву или жди тех, кому не придётся гуглить, что такое «Alpine Linux»... и для ввода команд, переключись на латиницу, с настройкой — аналогично...